# Erratic behaviour when scaling a centred div with CSS animation

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have a vertically + horizontally centred div that shows erratic, shaky movement when being resized with CSS animation.

The div is positioned absolutely, with fixed width / height and negative margins.

The animation itself is simply a toggle between two different sets of fixed width/height and negative margin values, with custom transition properties set.

It almost feels like the negative margins are being animated at different speeds to the width and height.

I've tried changing the CSS transition used (to linear, quart etc) as well using jQuery `animate()` instead of `css()` but they yield the same result.

Is anyone able to explain why this is happening and possibly a better way to do this, provided it works on IE >= 8?

**Example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/p4B3S/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        +
    </div>
</div>
<button>toggle</button>​
```

**CSS:**

```
.outer {
    /* easeOutQuart */
    -webkit-transition: all 750ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000); 
       -moz-transition: all 750ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000); 
        -ms-transition: all 750ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000); 
         -o-transition: all 750ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000); 
            transition: all 750ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000);

    position: absolute;

    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;

    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;

    margin-left: -100px;
    margin-top: -100px;

    outline: 1px solid red;       
}

.inner {
    position: absolute;

    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;

    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;    

    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-top: -20px;

    text-align: center;

    line-height: 40px;

    outline: 1px solid blue;    
}

button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$button = $('button');
$outer = $('.outer');

$button.toggle(function() {
    $outer.css({
        'width': '100px',
        'height': '100px',
        'margin-left': '-50px',
        'margin-top': '-50px'
    });
}, function() {
    $outer.css({
        'width': '200px',
        'height': '200px',
        'margin-left': '-100px',
        'margin-top': '-100px'        
    });    
});
```

Comment: I'm not able experiencing the shaky/eratic behavior your mentioning when using the jsfiddle example. I also tried increasing the ms to 2000ms to see if I could re-create the problem.

At this point, I'd probably try using the animate() to add/subtract the margin, height, and width and use jQuery to create the animation.

Comment: I do experience it in Chrome when I click the toggle button a couple times.  Just saying it as proof it is happening.

Comment: @JarrettBarnett — Interesting. What platform / browsers are you using? I'm on Mac 10.7.x and experience it across pretty much everything I got (Chrome 18, Safari 5.1 (+mobile), FF 11.0)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the rep to simply comment, so I'll give you my observations here.  There is no transition on IE8.0.7601.17514 64-bit.  It is either simply large or small..  The transition seems to work flawlessly in the diddle on my FF11 when running at 1920x1080 & 1440x720, however, when I resized my screen using the `Web Developer Toolbar` plug-in to 1280x720 and hit toggle, the red box transitioned, blue box remained static, and little black cross-hair vibrated and bounced all over the place; at 800x600, the red box transitioned properly, but the blue box in the middle that was previous static vibrated and could be called shaky and at 640x480 everything vibrated and bounced around..  Based on this, I would have to deduce that it has to do with your px defined sizes and fixed locations relative to screen-size/resolution and not anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer lies in the implementation of the **rounding of subpixel values.**

As far as I can tell Chrome 27.0 does not seems to have this issue but for most other browsers I believe it still unresolved.

> How this behavior is supposed to play out by the rendering engine isn’t dictated by the CSS specification, having it be left up to the implementation to render as it sees fit.

Above quote is from John Resig who has an interesting post on the subjet—along with heated comments on whether this is actually a desirable browser behaviour: http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/